# Zend_Translate class and space character

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate

I am using Zend_Translate with ini adapter in my project.

I want to know how it is possible to use space character in my ini file.

**Sample:**

```
ini file:
Show All = my translation // there is space between Show & All

view scipt:
echo $this->translate('Show All') // it doesnt translate
```

Comment: It is not possible simply because INI syntax don't allows it. Also any textual data should be wrapped with " (double quotes) especially if containing space and tabs characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't ( atleast i don't know a way ) , but you got it a bit wrong , think of the first parameter ( "Show All" ) as a constant or a variable , witch has some content that will changed in certan scenarios . For example i would use `$this->translate("SHOW_ALL");` .